# C# Изменение TexBox из 2 формы в первой

Tags: c#, winforms, form

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста в чём ошибка.
По нажатие по кнопки в Form1 открываеться(клонирутеся Form2) в панель причём форма 1 становиться владеющей форомй над второй

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.Owner = this;
frm2.TopLevel = false;
frm2.Parent = MainPanel;
frm2.Show();
```

Всё хорошо форма открылась, так же в 1 форме сделал label публичный что бы его видела вторая форма. Она видит, но при попытки выполнения выдаёт оишбку "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
Код второй формы:

```
                Form1 frm1 = (Form1)this.Owner;
                frm1.label1.Text = "Text - " + textBox1.Text;
                this.Close();
```

Comment: Нужно посмотреть текст исключения, какая именно переменная null.

Comment: Свойства `Owner` и `Parent` в данном случае являются взаимоисключающими. Когда вы назначаете `Parent`, `Owner` обнуляется.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov как же быть в данной ситвуации ?

Comment: Убрать строчку `frm2.Parent = MainPanel;`

Comment: @aepot Мне нужно обязательно что бы вторая форма появлялась в панели первой

Comment: Ну заведите поле в дочерней форме `public Form OwnerForm { get; set; }`, назначьте `frm2.OwnerForm = this;` и используйте `Form1 frm1 = (Form1)this.OwnerForm;`

Comment: @aepot Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: работа примера]

Форма ввода данных

```
public partial class FormInput : Form
{
    public FormInput()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //настраиваем кнопки
        this.AcceptButton = _buttonOK;
        this.CancelButton = _buttonCancel;
        _buttonOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    //свойство
    public string InputText => _textBoxInput.Text;
}
```

Главная форма

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _buttonInput.Click += ButtonInput_Click;
    }

    private void ButtonInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form = new FormInput();
        form.Owner = this;
        form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            _textBoxOutput.Text += form.InputText;
        }
    }
}
```